# String para Vetor(Arranjo) em C

Tags: c, string

estou fazendo uma tarefa de um código e preciso converter uma string, como por exemplo:
`123+*`
Em um vetor`(arranjo) do tipo:
`1 2 3 + *`
Alguém sabe como eu poderia fazer isso em C? Sou iniciante e gostaria de aprender. Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Ao que me consta uma string em C é um array de caracteres acrescido do caractere terminador '\0', assim sua string "123+*" está na memória como: '1', '2', '3', '+', '*', '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

Uma string/palavra é nada menos que um vetor de caracteres, ou seja, sua string já é um vetor. Você pode usa-la com tal assim:

```
char minha_string = "123+";
minha_string[0] = '2'; // Alterando o valor do 1 para o 2, agora a string é 223+
```

Caso você queira criar um outro vetor que tenha os valores da sua string então pode usar a biblioteca string.h e usar a função strcpy(vetor1, veotr2).
Outra solução:

```
for(int i = 0; i < QUANTIDADE_CARACTERE_DA_STRING_AQUI; i++)
{
    vetor1[i] = vetor2[i];
}
```